# AWS RDS upgrade from 8.0.11 to 8.0.19 fails

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade an RDS database from 8.0.11 to 8.0.17. or 8.0.19.

I started by creating a snapshot, restoring that snapshot, and then trying to upgrade to 8.0.17. The upgrade says it was successful, but the version is still showing 8.0.11

The upgrade log starts out with:

```
2018-11-22 16:11:40 Checking server version.
2018-11-22 16:11:40 Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
2018-11-22 16:11:45 Upgrading system table data.
2018-11-22 16:11:52 Checking system database.
```

then checks all the tables, each line which ends with an "OK".

```
2018-11-22 16:11:53 sys.sys_config OK
2018-11-22 16:11:53 Upgrade process completed successfully.
2018-11-22 16:11:53 Checking if update is needed.
END OF LOG
```

However, there are some errors in the PrePatchCompatibility.log:

```
7) Issues reported by 'check table x for upgrade' command
<schema>.<table> - No database selected
<schema>.<table> - Corrupt
<schema2>.<table> - No database selected
<schema2>.<table> - Corrupt
<schema3>.<table> - No database selected
<schema3>.<table> - Corrupt
```

When I connect to the database, I can't find anything wrong with that table, although it is in fact a view:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `<table>` AS ...
```

Any ideas? Removing the view allows the upgrade to succeed.

Comment: File a bug:  bugs.mysql.com

Comment: @RickJames - I'm not sure if it's a mysql or RDS issue.  Any idea how to tell?

Comment: File bugs with both.